# Trace linux bash call

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I was wondering if there is a way to trace where a command was run from in Linux.

For example, if I call a script, is there any way to trace where it was called from, like started from a program or another bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your script is written is bash, there is a built-in variable called $PPID (short for parent's process ID, I guess) that you can use to find out who called your script. Here is an example:

```
CALLER=$(ps ax | grep "^ *$PPID" | awk '{print $NF}')
echo I was called from $CALLER
```

**Explanation:**

1. The $PPID gives the process ID of the parent process (the caller)
2. the **ps** command lists all processes
3. The **grep** command looks for the line which contains the PPID at the start of the line
4. The **awk** command prints only the last column, which is the name of the caller

Answer (score 2):

"**Was** run from" is rather difficult I would think unless there is some logging in the executable that was run.  If the execution is finished there's probably not much left to look into.

If it **is** being executed, you might be able to get enough information on the caller from the parent process id(PPID) by simply using `ps`.

Answer (score 2):

If the process is still running then you can use the hierarchical visualization (called also forest or process tree) offered by the `ps` command.

Try for example:

```
ps xf
```

And the output will look like:

```
 3627 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/dash -f /usr/local/etc/wmii-hg/wmiirc
 3655 ?        S      0:38  \_ bwm --interface eth0 --download
 3656 ?        S      0:38  \_ bwm --interface eth0 --upload
 3687 ?        S      0:20  \_ /bin/dash -f /usr/local/etc/wmii-hg/wmiirc
  574 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ sleep 1
 3713 ?        S      0:00  \_ wmiir read /event
 3714 ?        S      0:00  \_ /bin/dash -f /usr/local/etc/wmii-hg/wmiirc
22671 ?        S      0:00      \_ /bin/dash -f /usr/local/etc/wmii-hg/wmiirc
22672 ?        Ss     0:03          \_ xterm
22673 pts/0    Ss+    0:00              \_ bash
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible upgrade to Hai Vu's answer:

```
ps -p $PPID -o args=
```

The `-p` restrict's the `ps` output to the process ID of the parent. The `-o` lets you specify your own output, and in this case I have `args=` which (for me gives me what I'm looking for). The possible upgrade is that instead of getting lots of info and then trying to parse it out, you're only asking `ps` for the info you want.

Once you have the `$PPID` you might also look in the `/proc/$PPID/` "dirs" to get more detailed info.